# The function evaluation was disabled because of an out of memory exception

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

i am getting this exception "The function evaluation was disabled because of an out of memory exception" from this line of code.

```
this.pbErrorSign.BackgroundImageLayout =   System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

I have actually added a background image and many other images like to warning image and picture boxes instead of buttons to make attractive GUI. Program was running fine some time ago and now its giving me this.... help plz

following code is from designer.

```
 this.pbErrorSign.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.pbErrorSign.BackgroundImage = global::SAMS.Properties.Resources.ErrorSign3;
        this.pbErrorSign.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
        this.pbErrorSign.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(69, 121);
        this.pbErrorSign.Name = "pbErrorSign";
        this.pbErrorSign.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 30);
        this.pbErrorSign.TabIndex = 1;
        this.pbErrorSign.TabStop = false;
```

following is the code of form named as errorDialogForm

```
public partial class ErrorDialogForm : Form
{
    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShown(e);
        this.Capture = true;
    }



    public ErrorDialogForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string LabelText
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lblError.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            this.lblError.Text = value;
        }
    }



    private void pbOkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void pbOkButton_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.pbOkButton.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.purpleOkButton));
    }

    private void pbOkButton_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.pbOkButton.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.blueOkButton));
    }



    private void ErrorDialogForm_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void ErrorDialogForm_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void ErrorDialogForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        this.Parent = null;
        e.Cancel = true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to include the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Comment: its a full form with designer code... should I upload that much code here?

Comment: You should upload more than is here, but do your best to trim out what's not relevant to the issue. see [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help on how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

> The function evaluation was disabled because of an out of memory exception

That's a debugger notification, it is simply telling you that it isn't going to show you anything because the program crashed with OOM.  Very high odds that the debugger will crash as well when that happens.  The *real* problem is the OOM exception you got that caused the debugger to stop the program.

> this.pbOkButton.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.purpleOkButton;

That's the statement that caused the crash.  You do this in events that fire very frequently as you move the mouse around.  What is not so obvious is that this statement creates a *new* Bitmap object.  The old ones are not being disposed.  That makes the memory usage of your program rapidly climb with low odds that the garbage collector can do anything about it because you don't allocate any other objects.  The OOM kaboom is pretty inevitable.

The proper fix is to create these bitmaps only once:

```
private Image purpleOk;
private Image blueOk;

public ErrorDialogForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    purpleOk = Properties.Resources.purpleOkButton;
    blueOk = Properties.Resources.blueOkButton;
    pbOkButton.BackgroundImage = blueOk;
}

private void pbOkButton_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.pbOkButton.BackgroundImage = purpleOk;
}

private void pbOkButton_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.pbOkButton.BackgroundImage = blueOk;
}

protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e) 
{
    purpleOk.Dispose();
    blueOk.Dispose();
    base.OnFormClosed(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Hans Passant. But I have done this in my all forms in the project. So I have to almost make them from the begining... Can I do anything to dispose currently made events like pbCancel_MouseEnter at form closing?

Comment: No.  You learned something new today, how you apply that knowledge to your programs is entirely up to you.  You have a lot more to learn, creating your own Button class so this code does not have to repeated over and over again should be next.

Comment: Well. . .Thanks for your help mate... Really appreciate it! :-)